# DB2 Using With Clause within inserts in stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I am using the below code inside the stored procedure.
It is working fine as long as I am not using the block for **TEMP_3**.
I got such like an error

**The data type for parameter or SQL variable "'WITH TEMP AS ( SELECT * FROM TABLEE" is not supported in the routine, compound SQL statement, or parameter list of a cursor value constructor.. SQLCODE=-789, SQLSTATE=429BB, DRIVER=4.28.11**

```
DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR S1;
'WITH TEMP AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM TABLEE 
        WHERE ID = 2
        )), 
        TEMP_1 AS (
        SELECT COUNT(1) AS ID FROM NEW TABLE (
        INSERT INTO TABLE_A (Col_1, Col_2)
        SELECT Col_1, 'A'
        FROM TABLE_A
        JOIN TABLEE ON ID = Col_1
        )),
        TEMP_2 AS (
        SELECT COUNT(1) AS ID FROM NEW TABLE (
        INSERT INTO TABLE_B (Col_1, Col_2)
        SELECT Col_1, 'B'
        FROM TABLE_B
        JOIN TABLEE ON ID = Col_1
        )),
        TEMP_3 AS (
        SELECT COUNT(1) AS ID FROM NEW TABLE (
        INSERT INTO TABLE_C (Col_1, Col_2)
        SELECT Col_1, 'C'
        FROM TABLE_C
        JOIN TABLEE ON ID = Col_1
        )),
        SELECT 1
        FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1';
  OPEN C1;
  CLOSE C1;
```

Comment: You can learn by studying the sample stored procedures. These are on your Db2-LUW server installation, they are in the Db2 knowledge centre online, and they are also on github, for example at https://github.com/IBM/db2-samples/tree/master/sqlpl

Answer (score 0):

Too many errors.
Just one target table example.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR S1;
  PREPARE S1 FROM 
  'WITH TEMP AS 
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLEE 
    WHERE ID = 2
  ), 
  TEMP_1 AS 
  (
     SELECT COUNT(1) AS ID 
     FROM NEW TABLE 
     (
        INSERT INTO TABLE_A (Col_1, Col_2)
        SELECT Col_1, ''A''
        FROM TABLE_A
        JOIN TABLEE ON ID = Col_1
     )
  )
  SELECT 1
  FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1';
  OPEN C1;
  CLOSE C1;
END
```

Please, provide full example with the corresponding `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements as well as in [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/hJdjXuM7) example.

Comment: Yeah I just figured out the problem, take a look here https://dbfiddle.uk/CcgO-DMV.
So far it is working fine, but I find out when I am using many dynamic parameters `''' || V || '''` I got the error above. Is their any solution for this?

Comment: These are not dynamic parameters. The way you do it is just building the whole statement dynamically every time, and probably you do some mistake, if you got the same error. Again, it's hard to comment without seeing actual code. Try to use real parameter markers as described [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/NdBHZhrr) to simplify the things. Note that: 1) you must use the same number parameters as question marks in the statement; 2) sometimes Db2 can't determine the data type of a parameter marker (not the case there) and you have to use `CAST (? AS data_type_needed)` instead just `?`.

Comment: Ok can we also sum up the list the of used parameters?, take a look here https://dbfiddle.uk/BUtzlszA.
In my example I will get an error due to Syntax, but is somethink like this possible **?1, ?2**

Comment: Named parameter markers are not supported in SQL routines. So, no, you can't use whatever parameter makers instead in SQL routines.